# How to tie notes at different time points into a chord?

Tags: lilypond

I am trying to tie notes that are in sequence into a single chord (effectively simulating a slow arpegio):

```
{
  \clef bass
  r8
  <<
    \relative c {
      <<
        \autoBeamOff \tieDown
        {cis8~ cis4~ cis8}
        {s32 e16.~ e4~ e8} 
        {s16 fisis16~ fisis4~ fisis8} 
        {s16. ais32~ ais4~ ais8}
        {s8 cis4 cis8}
      >>
    }
    \\
    \relative c{
      \mergeDifferentlyDottedOn cis32[ e fisis ais]
    }
  >>
}
```

The red ties are missing in Lilypond (2.19)
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command you are looking for is `\set tieWaitForNote = ##t`. This is how it looks with your example:

```
{
  \clef bass
  r8
  <<
    \relative c {
      <<
        \set tieWaitForNote = ##t
        \autoBeamOff \tieDown
        {cis8~ cis4~ cis8}
        {s32 e16.~ e4~ e8} 
        {s16 fisis16~ fisis4~ fisis8} 
        {s16. ais32~ ais4~ ais8}
        {s8 cis4 cis8}
      >>
    }
    \\
    \relative c{
      \mergeDifferentlyDottedOn cis32[ e fisis ais]
    }
  >>
}
```

Producing:

[image]

You might also want to use `\tieNeutral` for the chord and also set a `minimum-length` so that the top tie looks better:

```
{
  \clef bass
  r8
  <<
    \relative c {
      <<
        \set tieWaitForNote = ##t
        \autoBeamOff \tieDown
        {cis8~ cis4~ cis8}
        {s32 e16.~ e4~ e8} 
        {s16 fisis16~ fisis4~ fisis8} 
        {s16. 
         \override Staff.Tie.minimum-length = #5.2
         ais32~ ais4~ ais8}
        {s8 \tieNeutral cis4 cis8}
      >>
    }
    \\
    \relative c{
      \mergeDifferentlyDottedOn cis32[ e fisis ais]
    }
  >>
}
```

Producing:

[image]